# Understanding the execution of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a cell `<td>`:

And I have a script in jquery that when you double click it, it creates an `<input type="text">` like this:

```
$("td").dblclick(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        if($(event.target).prop("id")!="inputeditar"){ //WHEN I DOUBLE CLICK IN THE CELL
        // I paste the value of the cell into the value of the input


            $(document).one("click",function(event2){ //IF I CLICK OUT OF THE INPUT
            if($(event2.target).prop("id")!="input")
                 {
                 $("#input").remove(); //THEN I REMOVE IT

                 }
        });
        }


});
```

So If I double click on the space in the cell, then the input gets the text from the cell, and if I click outside of the input then it dissappears.

It works fine but if I click in the input (instead of outside) then it will never dissappear whenever I click outside of it. I would like to keep checking if I am clicking outside and then, removing the input.

Comment: wait... so, you want the input to be removed if you click the input? even if they click it to focus it or select text within it? that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: try adding snippet

Comment: if not input remove(), else re-add the `one()` event.  Or use `on` and `off`when you *do* remove (if you want to keep it inline).

Comment: @KevinB no, the "if I click out of the input" comment is in the wrong place

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Then .one isn't what you want, and you'll want to name the event handler so that you can unbound it without removing all other events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add events inside event handlers is generally a bad idea, but you can acheive what you want like this:

```
$(document).on("click",function(event2) { 
    if ($(event2.target).prop("id")!="input")
    {
        //IF I CLICK OUT OF THE INPUT
        //THEN I REMOVE IT
        $("#input").remove();
        $(document).off("click");
    }
})
```

**However** `$(document).off("click")` seems like a ***really*** bad idea!

Following KevinB's comment about naming event handlers, you should be able to add a namespace to the event handler and turn it off as required:

```
$(document).on("click.removeinput",function(event2) { 
    if ($(event2.target).prop("id")!="input")
    {
        //IF I CLICK OUT OF THE INPUT
        //THEN I REMOVE IT
        $("#input").remove();
        $(document).off("click.removeinput");
    }
})
```

(but I've personally never used event namespaces, so see how it goes)

---

Alternatively you can re-attach the `one()` by using a named function, eg :

```
..."dblclick".., function() { ...
    $(document).one("click", removeinput);


function removeinput(e) {
    if ($(e.target).prop("id")!="input")
    {
        //IF I CLICK OUT OF THE INPUT
        //THEN I REMOVE IT
        $("#input").remove();
    }
    else
       $(document).one("click", removeinput);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I managed to do it finally in the "alternative" way you suggested (the last one). Although I have made it calling the function like this:
removeinpit();

rather than this:
$(document).one("click", removeinput); // THIS was not working.

I appreciate your time. Thanks.